# Interpret output from Rasa chat interface and api

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

I have built a chatbot using Rasa core. I have followed all the steps mentioned in this documentation.(https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/).

I am running the bot in a Ubuntu virtual machine. After running the 6th step and the command `python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/current/nlu`

I get something like

```
root  - Rasa Core server is up and running on http://localhost:5005
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
```

When I try to chat with the bot:

```
Your input ->  hello
Hey! How are you?
127.0.0.1 - - [2020-02-27 12:20:49] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token= HTTP/1.1" 200 185 0.018887
```

I want to know what is this value of 0.018887?
Do I have a callable api running? Suppose my vm ip is 10.10.200.546, how can I call the api?
If not, how do I build a rest api to interact with my bot. Any references?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interact with Rasa chatbot hosted on a ubuntu vm through rest-api's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442113/how-to-interact-with-rasa-chatbot-hosted-on-a-ubuntu-vm-through-rest-apis)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know what is this value of 0.018887?

The debug info follows the format:
`[IP] - [Timestamp] [Method url] [response code] [response size] [request time]`

`127.0.0.1 - - [2020-02-27 12:20:49] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token= HTTP/1.1" 200 185 0.018887`

So, here, `0.1887` is your response time (in seconds).

> Do I have a callable api running? How can I call the api?

You need to explicitly enable the rest api. You can read more about it here: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/your-own-website/#id2