# How to interact with Rasa chatbot hosted on a ubuntu vm through rest-api's

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am new to building chatbots using Rasa. I have built a chatbot using Rasa core. I have followed all the steps mentioned in this documentation.(https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/quickstart/).

I am running the bot in a Ubuntu virtual machine. After running the 6th step and the command `python -m rasa_core.run -d models/dialogue -u models/current/nlu`

I get something like

```
root  - Rasa Core server is up and running on http://localhost:5005
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
```

When I try to chat with the bot:

```
Your input ->  hello
Hey! How are you?
127.0.0.1 - - [2020-02-27 12:20:49] "POST /webhooks/rest/webhook?stream=true&token= HTTP/1.1" 200 185 0.018887
```

I want to know what is this value of 0.018887?
Do I have a callable api running? Suppose my vm ip is 10.10.100.546, how can I call the api?
If not, how do I build a rest api to interact with my bot. Any references?

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend using a newer version of `rasa` here https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/ - the docs you refer to are for `<1.0`. The CLI became a lot more intuitive in `1.x`.

Even in the case of the old version however, there is an HTTP api specified here: https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/server/

that should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks. I have generated my training data based on the previous version of Rasa. That was a manual process of creating the stories.md file, domain.yml file and training_data.json file/nlu.md file.. Is there a way to automate this process or it has to be done manually only? Also, I find that there's a change in the format for new rasa version. How can I use my old stories.md, training_data.json, domain.yml files for the new rasa version?

Comment: The formatting changes for stories & nlu should be very minor between old and new versions - are you seeing errors when loading your data with the new version?